# Creating a HAVING COUNT(column) > 2 clause in pyDAL

Tags: count, having, pydal

I have the following pyDAL table:

```
market = db.define_table(
    'market',
    Field('name'),
    Field('ask', type='double'),
    Field('timestamp', type='datetime', default=datetime.now)
    )
```

I would like to use the expression language to execute the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM market 
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY timestamp DESCENDING
HAVING COUNT(name) > 1
```

I know how to do the `ORDER BY` and the `GROUP BY`:

```
db().select(
        db.market.ALL,
        orderby=~db.market.timestamp,
        groupby=db.market.name
    )
```

but I do not know how to do a count within a having clause even after reading [the section in the web2py book on the `HAVING` clause](https://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/06#groupby-having).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `count()` function returns an expression which can be used both as a field in the `select` query, and to build an argument to the query's `having` parameter. The [Grouping and counting](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Grouping-and-counting) section from the web2py manual has a few hints on this topic.

The following code will give the desired result. The row objects will hold both the `market` objects and their respective row counts.

```
count = db.market.name.count()
rows = db().select(
    db.market.ALL,
    count,
    groupby=db.market.name,
    orderby=~db.market.timestamp,
    having=(count > 2)
    )
```